# Detect if we have memory leak in Android studio

Tags: android

Recently I tried Android Studio
It seems my app is not working and after a while stops working!
Here is the profiler screenshot

[image]

My question is, How to detect the memory leak?
**As I press the dump head memory app stops from running.**

> Are the sharp edges represents the memory leak?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/square/leakcanary

Answer (score 6):

> Are the sharp edges represnts the memory leak?

No. It's the other way around. The sharp edges you see result from the garbage collector reclaiming memory from your app. With a memory leak, your app's memory usage would increase over time.

However, it seems your app is creating lots of objects. This is normal as long as your app actually does something useful (i.e. not just sitting there waiting for user input).

Comment: Thanks alot. I was actually looking for something you replied.

Answer (score 2):

There are different methods for checking Memory Leak in Android

One of most famous is [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) by square

> A memory leak detection library for Android and Java.
>
> “A small leak will sink a great ship.” - Benjamin Franklin

**In your build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.2'
  releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.6.2'
}
```

**In your Application class:**

```
public class ExampleApplication extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
      // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
      // You should not init your app in this process.
      return;
    }
    LeakCanary.install(this);
    // Normal app init code...
  }
}
```

**In your Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name=".ExampleApplication"
    ...
 >
```

Comment: I try this one, but I couldn't get it handled, since I'm new to android world

Comment: You must register this in manifest as an application too. It will be installed as a seperated application running in the background. When leak occurs you will get a notification on status bar.

Comment: cannot resolve method `isInAnalyzerProcess` error shown in compile

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio has a handy tool for detecting memory leaks. If you suspect a piece of code in you app might leaks an Activity, you can do this.

Step 1: Compile and run the debug build on a device or emulator connecting to you computer.

Step 2: Go to the suspicious activity, then go back to previous activity which will pop the suspicious activity from the task stack. If you don't know the activity just play with the app for some time.

When you first open the Memory Profiler, you'll see a detailed timeline of your app's memory use and access tools to force garbage collection, capture a heap dump, and record memory allocations.

Now follow the b below steps from Android Developers Guide in memory profiler section:

[View the Java heap and memory allocations with Memory Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler)